# Odd behavior on printing function addresses in Python

Tags: python, function, printing, function-address

I write the following code in **Python**:

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a + b

print(fib, fib(10))
```

I think the correct output should be:

```
<function fib at 0x000001DF4BB13E18> 1 1 2 3 5 8
```

But The output is:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 <function fib at 0x000001C60F823E18> None
```

The code prints **None** and its behavior is odd.

Why behavior of `print` function is odd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is correct. It's just that `fib(10)` is executed before you call `print`. That's because the arguments for the function call have to be executed before they are passed to the function.

So in fact you do calculate `fib(10)` (including all the `print`s inside the function) and then print `fib` and the result from the `fib(10)` call (which is `None` because your `fib` function contains no explicit `return`).

You can also invoke `dis.dis` to see the order of evaluation:

```
def f():
    print(fib, fib(10))

import dis

dis.dis(f)
```

Result:

```
 10           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (fib)
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (fib)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1             ----> the fib(10) call
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            2             ----> the print call
                                         ^-------  number of arguments!
             12 POP_TOP
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: "the values in parenthesis are always executed first" is misleading, considering that in cases like `f() + (g() + h())`, `f()` is evaluated before `g()` or `h()`.

Comment: Good use for `dis`

Answer (score 3):

Both arguments to `print()` are fully evaluated before `print()` is actually called. Since the second argument to your main `print()` is `fib(10)`, `fib` is called with argument `10` during this process. And since it prints things, these get printed during the evaluation process. The function itself doesn't contain a `return` statement, so it returns `None`, which is why that's printed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down.

First we'll look at the ordering:

```
print(fib, fib(10))
```

The call to fib will be evaluated first and pass its returned value into the print function.

fib(10) will do some printing of it's own and then exit. In this case it doesn't explicitly return a value and so gets treated as `None`

The above call to print can therefore be seen as

```
print(fib, None)
```

Which will result in printing the function address and then `None`

Comment: "Functions are always evaluated first" is not true.

Comment: Poorly phrased. evaluated before the function that they're contained within. Will edit